# Find all the points for which $f(z)=(z-1)(Re(z))^2$ is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all the points for which $f(z)=(z-1)(Re(z))^2$ is differentiable.

So I tried setting $z=re^{it}$, but it made it more complex for me when I tried using the definition on some arbitrary point $z_0=r_0e^{it_0}$. What is the proper way of solving such problems?

Thanks in advance, and cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $z \mapsto (Re(z))^2$ is not differentiable except possibly on the line $x = 0$. (Try proving so yourself; an easy proof is to show that evaluating the standard difference quotient along horizontal lines and vertical lines produces different results.)  Given this fact, write $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$.  If $x_0 \neq 0$ and $z_0 \neq 1$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $z_0$; otherwise, by the quotient rule $z \mapsto (Re(z))^2$ would be differentiable at $z_0$, a contradiction.

Meanwhile if $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0 \neq 0$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $z_0$ either.  To see why, let $g$ be the principal branch of the square root function.  Away from the nonpositive $x$-axis and $z = 1$, one can write $Re(z) =  g \left(\frac{f(z)}{z-1} \right)$, which implies by the chain rule and a similar contradiction proof that $f$ is not differentiable at any such point $z_0$.

You can prove that $f$ is differentiable at each of $0$ and $1$ by the product rule and by the limit definition of the derivative, respectively.

Some general advice for solving this type of problem is be sure to prove both that the function is differentiable at all of your proposed points *and* to prove that it is not differentiable at any other point.  Keep a running library of functions that are differentiable and functions that are not.  Try not to resort to evaluating limits unless you have to.

Comment: "Note that $z \mapsto (Re(z))^2$ is not differentiable except at $z_0=0$." Hmmm, this seems quite wrong, no?

Comment: Ah, you are right; all that my “proof” did was to show that if $z \mapsto Re(z)$ is differentiable at $z_0$, then $x_0 = 0$.  I have edited accordingly.  Incidentally, I *had* proved (for later use) that it is differentiable at $0$; I just didn’t want to give away too much in case this was homework.

Comment: Wait, @Did. By composing the principal branch of square root with $z \mapsto (Re(z))^2$, one can still show that $z \mapsto (Re(z))^2$ is not differentiable on the $y$- axis except at $z = 0$, no?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann.